# ReSharper failing to run NUnit tests

Tags: visual-studio-2010, nunit, resharper

I am trying to get NUnit working within Visual Studio 2010, using ReSharper's test runner.  NUnit version is 2.5.10, and ReSharper's version is 5.1.3000.12.

When I try to run my tests, it throws the following error:

> Unit Test Runner failed to load test assembly:
>   JetBrains.ReSharper.TaskRunnerFramework.TaskException: Could not load file or assembly 'file:///C:\Documents and Settings\Administrator\Local Settings\Temp\jwgjsyeb.0ui' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Anybody know if these versions are incompatible?  According to [this discussion](http://devnet.jetbrains.net/message/5279977), it they may be incompatible. If so, should I drop my version of NUnit?  If so, to what version, and what will I be missing out on?  If there's that big a difference, I may consider running my tests outside VS2010.

Or, if they should be compatible, then what other issue may be causing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hit this one sometime last month & got the response below from jet brains. As you can see, the support tech says the last official supported nunit is 2.5.8.

I am actually using r#'s runner with v2.5.9.10348, although I would *dearly* love to see the it treated as a 1st class citizen and actually maintained to keep in synch with Nunit. I'd go off on a rant again about jet brains greedy release policy, as I did [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6154703/resharper-latest-builds) but ... it probably wouldn't help!

2.5.9 is worth a shot, like I said I use it. 2.5.8, while ancient, is actually 'officially supported' in any event.

Cheers,
Berryl

```
I'm afraid that ReSharper 5.1.3 doesn't support NUnit 2.5.10 (the last 
supported version is 2.5.8 for the R#5.1.3).

ReSharper 6 EAP builds should work fine with the latest NUnit release. You 
may download the EAP builds from here: 
http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/ReSharper/ReSharper+6.0+Nightly+Builds.
Please let me know if it helps.

Thank you.

________________________
Alex Berezoutsky,
Support Engineer
JetBrains, Inc.
http://www.jetbrains.com
"Develop with pleasure!"
```

Answer (score 0):

After some trial and error, the latest version of NUnit I can get to work with ReSharper 5.1.3000.12, is [NUnit 2.5.7](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=download).

[Here](http://www.nunit.org/index.php?p=releaseNotes&r=2.5.10) is the list of revisions made, starting at the latest stable build, 2.5.10.